# I've two tables a trigger that's auto filling the 2nd table. How can I fetch data so that null values for an attribute will be avoided automatically?

Tags: mysql, database, database-trigger

I've two tables  a trigger that's auto filling the 2nd table. 
How can I fetch data so that null values for an attribute will be avoided automatically?

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
department_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (department_id),
UNIQUE (department_name));

CREATE TABLE `designations_of_departments` (
department_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
designation_1 VARCHAR(30),
designation_2 VARCHAR(30),
designation_3 VARCHAR(30),
designation_4 VARCHAR(30),
designation_5 VARCHAR(30),
FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
    REFERENCES departments (department_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);

delimiter $$
create trigger trigger_1 after insert on departments
for each row begin 
insert into designations_of_departments(department_id, designation_1, designation_2, designation_3, designation_4, designation_5) 
values (new.department_id, null, null, null, null, null);
end$$ delimiter ;
```

I tried with this query, but it still shows null values.

```
select * from designations_of_departments
where not (designation_1 <=> null and designation_2 <=> null and
designation_3 <=> null and designation_4 <=> null and designation_5 <=>
null) and department_id=1;
```

Example :

```
INSERT INTO `departments` VALUES (1,'HRM'), (2,'Accounting')(3,'Engineering');

UPDATE designations_of_departments SET 
designation_1 = 'Senior HR',
designation_2 = 'HR',
designation_3 = 'Junior HR' WHERE department_id = 1;
```

This is what I tried according to suggestion in comments :

```
select * from designations_of_departments
where designation_1 is not null
 and designation_2 is not null
 and designation_3 is not null
 and designation_4 is not null
 and designation_5 is not null
 and department_id=1;
```

Comment: The key word in mysql for null values is : **'IS NULL'** or **'IS NOT NULL'**

Comment: changed and tested, still shows null values.

Comment: I've edited, it still shows null values. I think I'm mistaking somewhere. Would appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: department_id=1 has 3 designations, I dont want to show null values in output, it is possible? designation_4 and designation_5 shall not appear in output since they contain null values.

Comment: Can you edit again your question to show the output you expect with the example you give ?

Comment: You want to remove columns with `NULL`s from the result? That would require dynamic SQL.

Comment: that's what I want. thanks for pointing it out. would you like to suggest something? @stickybit